# Is there a getSimpleName() equivalent for writing method names in log statements?

Tags: java, android

Currently I write my log statements like this:

```
Log.i(TAG, MyClass.class.getSimpleName() + "#methodName" + someThing);
```

Is there a way to reference a method name similar to a `Class's` `getSimpleName()` that doesn't involve a hard coded `String`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName();`

```
String methodName = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName();
Log.i(TAG, MyClass.class.getSimpleName() + methodName + someThing);
```